# How to connect a client to a PHP application on Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a basic Client-Server environment.

Here are the details:

**Client:** I created an Android app that opens an HTTP connection:

```
        String url = "http://MYAPPNAME.elasticbeanstalk.com"; 
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

**Server:** I created:

1. RDS instance with one table called "users".
2. Elastic Beanstalk application. I deployed a PHP file (in a Zip file). The PHP file contains a connection to the DB (RDS) and executes the statement: "SELECT * FROM users"

I Get an error in the first connection between the client and the PHP application:

[image: The error]

The security group allows everyone to get to this instance:

80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0

Is someone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: That does not look like a response from a php script. But more from the web server.

Comment: I created a new application with Enviroment tier: Worker instead of Web server as it was before.
now I get red monitor after deploying. I get this Error in the log: 2014-10-04T16:00:35Z error: AWS::SQS::Errors::AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/311148171554/..... is denied.

Comment: Are you trying with a https url?

Comment: I didn't understand. I get "Environment health has been set to RED" in the Dashboard of Elastic Beanstalk. I didn't try to connect yet.

Comment: I changed back to Web server as an Enviroment tier. it works now. Thank you very much (see my comment to the second answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access to the root directory ("/"). If you could access in that easy way, everybody could. Nobody (without authentication) should be able to access.

Change the path to your path (http://MYAPPNAME.elasticbeanstalk.com/....." and/or define an entry point.

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: What should be the path ?

Comment: It depends if your want to get via REST & JSON (you should have an API) or if you only want to load a webpage (you should indicate fullpath to the file. For example: "http://MYAPPNAME.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.html"). Every server it's totally different. Nevertheless, your answer, it's not a server question, it's a bad path.

I would try, for example,  http://MYAPPNAME.elasticbeanstalk.com/users.php for your case, or your file fullpath in the server

Comment: YAY it works! thank you. I'm sure that I tried the path with the php and it didn't work.... Now it works!!! Thank you very much!!